# USB host programming on Android starting with 3.1 - experience with slickdevlabs USB library

Tags: android, usb, host

I am looking for a solution to do USB host programming on Android using the new USB features.

Does anyone have experience with this already? Does it really work? Are there any particular limitations? What would be the best place to start?

I checked http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/host.html, but ideally need a working example.

I would regret the investment in a new Android phone/tablet just to do the development and then find out that certain USB functions do not work.

What I am particularly interested in is if there is experience doing serial communication over a FTDI chip using Android USB host programming.

In particular I would like to know if anybody has used the library from slickdevlabs to do this - is it worth it or can one just pick up any example code (like bluetooth) and go from there?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's been coincidentally a year exactly since you asked this question, but I am currently using the slickdev library to talk to FTDI devices. There is an issue however.

Somewhere along the line, I lose a few bytes of data, as well as picking up in my data the header bytes. So I am losing like 3 bytes of data, but gaining 4 bytes of header data. The header data is 0x0162, basically saying it's sending 62 bytes of data.

I'm still hoping to use the slickdev library, but unless I can get around that issue, I'm going to have to write something from scratch, under the pretense that writing from scratch will allow me the control I need in order to change settings not allowed control over with slick.

Comment: what do you need exactly the lib for? Communication via USB is really straight forward, possibly the only issue is timeout and asynchronous communication. Let me know what exactly is your issue...

Comment: For Serial FTDI device communication. I am not super knowledgeable on how to do all the communication stuff at the lowest android-programming level. There are multiple devices that are needing communicating with, with at least one more to add to the list in the near future.
Regarding my current issue, I get header bits 0x0162 with the data that I do get, as well as missing about 3 bytes of actual data at the end. With the slick lib, I'm not able to change the setting/variable that may be the actual cause.

Comment: are you sure it's an issue of the lib? why don't you just read yourself directly without the lib and see if the problem remains? I also had some unwanted unexplainable bytes - I just learned to deal with it and skip them in my app...

Comment: I've actually talked to FTDI programmers and they told me they ran into the same issue testing with the Slick Dev. I currently am just taking them out, but the problem still remains that actual data is lost.

Comment: ..I guess then I was lucky, because in my case these strange header bytes can all be savely ignored in my case and all the remaining bytes are correct and nothing is missing in my case ...

Comment: Well the header bytes can be successfully ignored and all the data will be there when... the data block isn't completely full. So the only time I lose actual data is when I am getting a full block of data. Other than that, it works great! haha